# APEX_LISTENER and APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER are not being created

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-apex, oracle-18c

I am trying to install APEX 19.1 on ORACLE XE 18c but the problem is that APEX_LISTENER and APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER are not being created. While I execute apex_rest_config.sql script via sqlplus, an error message appears saying: **GetConsoleMode failed, Last Error=|6|**

Then I check the list of users and I see that these two users are not created. Is this a bug of APEX installation? Please can anybody help?

Comment: Did you get it working properly?
I reinstalled using exactly what I saw as the answer and it gave the same ressulting error. Thanks, BillC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you tried installing APEX in the root container, I was able to reproduce the error.

Oracle Express Edition 18c uses the CDB architecture, meaning you have a root container and a pluggable database called XEPDB1.

Whatever you did, you should do it inside the `XEPDB1` pluggable database instead of the `CDB$ROOT` root container. I am not saying it can not work like that, I just would not bother with it.

[Understanding the Installation Choices](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/understanding-installation-choices.html)

> Oracle recommends removing Oracle Application Express from the root
>   container database for the majority of use cases, except for hosting
>   companies or installations where all pluggable databases (PDBs)
>   utilize Oracle Application Express and they all need to run the exact
>   same release and patch set of Oracle Application Express.

So if you log in with `sqlplus / as sysdba`, you can change to `XEPDB1` like this:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO
SQL> alter session set container=XEPDB1;

Session altered.

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
XEPDB1
```

To fix what you have, just log in with `sqlplus / as sysdba` and remove everything with `apxremov.sql`. Then log in like above, into the `XEPDB1` pluggable database, and try again installing APEX. You can use these steps:

[Downloading and Installing Oracle Application Express](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/downloading-installing-Oracle-AE.html)